# url redirect to case team edit page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, urlhacking

With no out of the box lightning option for case team member edit atm, the temp solution is to url my way to the classic page, which worked fine in visualforce page.

```
action="{!$Site.Prefix}/0B6/e?kp=500&pid={!cobj.Id}&retURL={!$Site.Prefix}/{!cobj.Id}" />
```

The problem is if I try to navigate there using **e.force:navigateToURL** to ie:

'0B6/e?kp=500&pid=recordid&retURL=recordid'

it appends a 'one/' in front, which breaks the site. removing the one/ manually fixes the problem... but I wonder if there is anyway I can handle that to open that page probably?